# WooCommerce ajax fetch order status & redirect to url

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to check the order status continuously using ajax and if I get the order status is "processing" then I want to redirect the customer to a specific URL. I tried below snippet but it didn't work.

```
<script>
function fetchStatus()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=fetch_order_status&order_id=<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>',
        type : 'post',      
        error : function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        success : function( response ){
            window.location.href = "url to redirect";
        }
    });
}
setInterval(fetchStatus, 1000);
</script>
```

In `functions.php`:

```
<?php
function fetch_order_status(){
    $order = wc_get_order( $_REQUEST['order_id'] );
    $order_data = $order->get_data();
    if($order->has_status == 'processing'){
        echo $order_data['status'];
    }
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fetch_order_status', 'fetch_order_status');
add_action('wp_ajax_fetch_order_status','fetch_order_status');
?>
```

Comment: please try the code now. I just made changes in your code.

Comment: I tried but still, it's not working..

Comment: In the beginning of function `fetchStatus()` add `console.log('begin fetchStatus)` and then take a look at javascript console. Also take a look at the Nertwork Tab in developer tools to see whether there is any request sent to server.

Comment: hi @AedvaldTseh didn't get what you are saying. can you please tell me in brief thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is the thing I did:

```
function fetchStatus()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>?action=fetch_order_status&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>',
        type : 'post',
        dataType:"json",
        error : function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        success : function( response ){
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status == "processing") {

                window.location.href = "URL to redirect";
            } else {
                fetchStatus();
            }
        }
    });
}
fetchStatus();
</script>
```

and in function.php:

```
function fetch_order_status(){
    $order = wc_get_order( $_REQUEST['order_id'] );
    $order_data = $order->get_data();
    echo json_encode(array("status"=>$order_data['status']));
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fetch_order_status', 'fetch_order_status');
add_action('wp_ajax_fetch_order_status','fetch_order_status');
```

Answer (score 0):

[has_status](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#1910-1918) is a method, that accepts an argument. It returns a boolean, not a string.

Maybe try `$order->has_status( 'processing' );`.

Also - update the `success` logic:

```
    success : function( response ){
        if (response === 'DESIRED_STATUS') {
            window.location.href = "url to redirect";
        }
    }
```

Where, `DESIRED_STATUS` is the status you're waiting for to make the redirect.

#### Answer without race conditions

Since you're making an HTTP request, it is possible for a [race condition](https://medium.com/@slavik57/async-race-conditions-in-javascript-526f6ed80665) to happen.

```
<script>
function fetchStatus()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>?action=fetch_order_status&order_id=<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>'
        type : 'post',
        error : function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        success : function( response ){
            if (response === 'DESIRED_STATUS') {
                window.location.href = "url to redirect";
            } else {
                fetchStatus();
            }
        }
    });
}

fetchStatus();
</script>
```

Comment: hi, I have changed desired_status to processing and checked but it's still not redirecting.

Comment: Do you have an error in the console? Can you check the network tab of the DevTools (for Chrome), to see if the request is being made?

Comment: I checked console its clear. but while debugging I got **Notice: Trying to get property 'status' of non-object**

Comment: Can you paste the whole line for the notice? Which object displayed it?

Comment: hi sry plz ignore the notice I tried to print the status as per the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001915/woocommerce-ajax-fetch-order-status) but it's also not working

Comment: Can you check the source of the page, to see if the JS in the `script` tag is properly displaying the URL for the AJAX?

Comment: hi I have checked source and it shows script at the bottom of the page with some error like: **Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_order_number()**

Comment: I suspected something like this. Where does the `$order` variable come from? Also - where is this code located?

Comment: I have added custom payment wechat in my website and this is the page where customer will get the qr code to scan and pay. So I want to redirect this page after payment has been done. And page url is site.com/payment/orderid like google.com/payment/3121

Comment: You'll need an instance of the order, in order to call the `get_order_number` method. If you have the ID in PHP, you can create one using the following code: `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );`, where `$order_id` should contain the ID of the order from the URL.

Comment: yeah I got the complete script in the source of the page without any error and also got the order id from it. but got this error in console: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

Comment: Can you please paste the complete error? I can't help you if I don't see the whole picture :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your support. I solved it by using json format and my own instance and with the help of your above code.